# QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor - get content response

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I'm able to catch requested urls by installing custom request interceptor but`QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo` contains only urls. Is it also possible to catch content which is return by those requests?

```
void RequestInterceptor::interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo &info)
{
    qDebug() << "IN " << info.requestMethod().toStdString().data() << " " << info.initiator().toString();
    qDebug() << "FP " << info.requestMethod().toStdString().data() << " " << info.firstPartyUrl().toString();
    qDebug() << "RL " << info.requestMethod().toStdString().data() << " " << info.requestUrl().toString();
}
```

Comment: The intersection of QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor is given before the request, so there is no information that you want.

Comment: Yes, I expected that but thought that maybe there is similar way to get content. Some Response Interceptor etc

Comment: Unfortunately there is no public method, perhaps if you dig into the private API of Qt WebEngine and chromium

Comment: Did you find out a way to intercept the content response data in the end please?